# Pyspark window functions (lag and row_number) generate inconsistent results

Tags: pyspark

I have been fighting an issue with window functions in pyspark for a few weeks now.

I have the following query to detect changes for a given key field:

```
rowcount = sqlContext.sql(f"""
with temp as (
select key, timestamp, originalcol, lag(originalcol,1) over (partition by key order by timestamp) as lg
from snapshots
where originalcol is not null
)
select count(1) from (
select *
from temp
where lg is not null
and lg != originalcol
)
""")
```

Data types are as follows:

- key: string (not null)
- timestamp: timestamp (unique, not null)
- originalcol: timestamp

The snapshots table contains over a million records. This query is producing different row counts after each execution: 27952, 27930, etc. while the expected count is 27942. I can say it is only approximately correct, with a deviation of around 10 records, however this is not acceptable as running the same function twice with the same inputs should produce the same results.

I have a similar problem with row_number() over the same window, then filtering for row_number = 1, but I guess the issue should be related.

I tried the query in an AWS Glue job as both pyspark and athena SQL, and the inconsistencies are similar.

Any clue about what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of research, I discovered that column timestamp is not unique. Even though SQL Server manages to produce the same execution plan and results, pyspark and presto get confused with the order by clause in the window function and produce different results after each execution. If anything can be learned from this experience, it would be to double-check the partition and order by keys in a window function.

Comment: You can convert timestamp into unix_timestamp, so it'll work.

Comment: Hi SakuraFreak, actually the granularity wouldn't change in this scenario, because the error was also present in the source system. But your suggestion could work in case there was some kind of loss due to data type conversion.

Answer (score 2):

Spark is pretty picky about some silly things...

`and lg != originalcol` doesn't detect ***Null*** values and thus the first value from the window partition will always be filtered out (since the first value from LAG will always be ***Null***).

The same thing happens when you try using ***Null*** using ***In*** statment

Another example where Null will filter-out:

```
where test in (Null, 1)
```

Comment: In my query, I am already checking for null values, precisely to avoid this issue:
=> where originalcol is not null
=> where lg is not null